# syntax error when using byacc

Tags: compiler-errors, yacc

When using byacc, getting following error.

```
byacc -d -p ws_yy_ wmlscript/wsgram.y && mv y.tab.c wmlscript/wsgram.c
byacc: e - line 111 of "wmlscript/wsgram.y", syntax error
%pure_parser
^
make: *** [wmlscript/wsgram.c] Error 1
```

---

```
byacc version: 1.9 20070509
system info: RHEL 6.4 64 bit
```

Please suggest which version of byacc supports re-entrant code. I found the suggestion of touching the `wsgram.y` file when I did bit of research on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [byacc Changelog](http://invisible-island.net/byacc/CHANGES) says `%pure-parser` was added in February, 2010:

> 2010-02-16  Thomas E. Dickey
>
> - skeleton.c:
>     implement %pure-parser, like bison.  To help with this, changed the stack
>     variables, putting them into a struct.

So I guess you're going to need an upgrade.